# System.ArgumentException: "Недопустимый параметр."

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Через несколько секунд после запуска останавливается с ошибкой. Что я делаю не так?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }

    public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var forma1 = new Form1();
        var x = PointToClient(MousePosition);
        var y = forma1.Size;
        label1.Text = x.ToString() + y.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: в диагностике память процесса резко подскакивает до 3гб. Предположительно из за того, что в цикле создаю "var forma1 = new Form1();"  но как сделать по другому незнаю

Comment: У вас интервал таймера какой? Вы как часто создаете новые окна? И зачем вы их создаете?

Comment: чтобы при изменении размера окна узнать его размер, т.к в таймере не дает напрямую спросить "y = Form1.size;"

Comment: Сначала нужно изменить размер, потом передать значение в таймер.

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы уже после запуска программы, когда пользователь тянет за уголок окна изменяя его размер, узнать размер получившейся формы; Учитывая что он может сделать это не один раз, я закинул это в таймер.

Comment: Жестокое решение! Не используйте таймеры для таких задач, обращайте внимания на события которые генерируют сущности и подписывайтесь на них.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не понимаете, что делаете. Не создавайте новую форму, она вам не нужна. Замените `var forma1 = new Form1();` на `var forma1 = this;`. Увеличьте интервал вашего таймера, если этого ещё не сделали. Для чего вам тут нужна x - вообще загадка.

Но вообще у формы есть событие `SizeChanged` которое вызывается при изменении размера формы. Например,

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Label label;

    public Form1()
    {
        label = new Label() {Width = 200};
        this.Controls.Add(label);


        this.SizeChanged += (sender, args) => {
            label.Text = this.Size.ToString();
        };
    }
}
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]